# Is RDRAND used in a safe way by Windows 10?

Tags: random, windows-10

This question was already [answered](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/09/10/torvalds_on_rrrand_nsa_gchq/) by Linus Torvalds for Linux, and is also cited in [this Q/A](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42164/rdrand-from-dev-random) on this stack:

> We use rdrand as _one_ of many inputs into the random pool, and we use it as a way to _improve_ that random pool. So even if rdrand were
>   to be back-doored by the NSA, our use of rdrand actually improves the
>   quality of the random numbers you get from /dev/random.

What is the status for Windows 10? Does Windows provide a random source mixing RDRAND with other sources or any sofisticated processing that can countermeasure possible backdoors in RDRAND? Or is there a set of possibilities and one should scrutanize every windows library case by case?

Comment: The title of the question is not very clear, would it be ok to change it to something like "_Is RDRAND used in a safe way by Windows 10?_" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## In short:

Maybe (see the Conclusions).

---

## Documents

Windows's default random generation process is described in considerable detail in its Common Criteria and FIPS 140 validation documents.

For [Common Criteria](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/products/#OS) in the Windows "*Security Target*" documents.
For [FIPS](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/validated-modules/search) in the Microsoft's "*Kernel Mode Cryptographic Primitives Library*" and "*OS Loader*" ones.

Do get all three of them, there are details in the Common Criteria documents absent from the FIPS ones, and vice-versa.

These are the most recent versions at the moment of writing, which apply to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update:

- [**Common Criteria** Microsoft Windows 10 and Microsoft Windows Server (Fall Creators Update) - Security Target](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/epfiles/2018-04-ST.pdf) (2018-07)
- [**FIPS** 140-2 CMVP #3196 - Microsoft **Kernel Mode** Cryptographic Primitives Library - Security Policy](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3196.pdf) (2018-09)
- [**FIPS** 140-2 CMVP #3194 - Windows **OS Loader** - Security Policy](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/Certificate/3194) (2018-09)

I also found this **paper** from 2015 which analyzes the topic in some detail:
[Windows and Linux Random Number Generation Process: A Comparative Analysis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6b0d/a7c081d9388f304bf6499db373b8d83).

It treats Windows 8, though  (for example, you might notice that it mentions the infamous Dual_EC_DRBG, but that was removed in Windows 10).

---

## Details

Since StackOverflow usually doesn't like links, I replicate here most of the details:

### | Boot-time seed

First, a 512-bits boot-time entropy seed is generated:

> Entropy is gathered from the following sources, when they are available on the computer:
>
> 1. The contents of the registry value HKLM\System\RNG\Seed, which is written by the Kernel
>    Mode Cryptographic Primitives Library (cng.sys) during its normal operation.
> 2. The contents of the registry value HKLM\System\RNG\ExternalEntropy, which can be
>    populated by system administrators. This value is overwritten after reading, to ensure that it
>    is not reused.
> 3. If a Trusted Platform Module (TPM) is available, the output of a TPM_GetRandom call to the
>    TPM.
> 4. The current system time.
> 5. The contents of the OEM0 ACPI table in the machine firmware.
> 6. If the CPU supports instructions for the RDSEED ( used when available) or RDRAND (used if
>    RDSEED is not available), the output from RDSEED or RDRAND.
> 7. The output of the UEFI random number generator.
> 8. The CPU timings.
>
> These inputs are then combined using SHA-512, and the entropy source is conditioned using a
> non-Approved RNG. From this NDRNG, a block of output bytes is passed to the Windows kernel
> at boot time

<sub>source: [FIPS OS Loader](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/Certificate/3194)</sub>

#### Notes:

I'm not sure what they mean with "*conditioned using a non-Approved RNG*".

### | Entropy pool

At runtime, at all times, there is then a "Windows entropy pool", which

> is populated using the following values:
>
> - An initial entropy value from a seed file provided to the Windows OS Loader at boot time (512
>   bits of entropy). <sub>*(the boot-time seed)*</sub>
> - A calculated value based on the high-resolution CPU cycle counter which fires after every 1024
>   interrupts (a continuous source providing 16384 bits of entropy).
> - Random values gathered periodically from the Trusted Platform Module (TPM), (320 bits of
>   entropy on boot, 384 bits thereafter on demand based on an OS timer).
> - Random values gathered periodically by calling the RDRAND CPU instruction, (256 bits of
>   entropy).

<sub>source: [Common Criteria](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/epfiles/2018-04-ST.pdf)</sub>

> The Windows DRBG infrastructure located in cng.sys continues to gather entropy from these sources
> during normal operation, and the DRBG cascade is periodically reseeded with new entropy

<sub>source: [FIPS Kernel Mode](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3196.pdf)</sub>

#### Notes:

**I was unable to find out how these sources are combined**, *if they even are*.

Maybe they use the same system as the boot-time sources, maybe they are just laid out one after another and taken up in turns :o .

The [2015 paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6b0d/a7c081d9388f304bf6499db373b8d83) seems to assume that they're combined in the same way as the boot-time seed, but I couldn't find any sources to substantiate that and I think it's likely that the authors jumbled up the two by mistake.

### | BCryptGenRandom

The recommended function for obtaining random data, [BCryptGenRandom](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom), then works by using this pool
as a seed for a NIST [SP 800-90A](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1) AES-256 counter mode based DRBG.

---

## Conclusions

It *might* be a good system, and so RDRAND might be being used in a good way, but until someone clarifies if and how the entropy pool sources are combined, I don't think we can really tell.
It would be very surprising if the pool sources were not mixed-up, but then again... maybe not so much.

In any case, I must emphasize that **I'm not really an expert** in this field, I might well have missed something and it might even be that it wouldn't matter if the sources weren't mixed.
I meant to only reports the documents that I found, but as I noticed these things I thought I would mention them as well.

Wait for the opinion of some qualified cryptographer before drawing a conclusion (and most of all, of course, try to find out how this pool really works).

---

## Notes

- Of course keep in mind that this is just the *recommended* way to get random data, any application is free to use what it wants.
- Note also that as these certifications might (I'm not certain) apply only when Windows is running in **FIPS mode**, this information might be guaranteed to be valid only when that mode is enabled.
  One sure difference is that only in FIPS mode there are some self-tests performed on the DRBG on start-up and during a reseed, as mandated by [SP 800-90A](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1) (but there are probably few circumstances in which they would be useful).
- Of course this is always a closed-source system, updated all the time, so we can't be a hundred percent sure of what it really does (unless we don't reverse-engineer our own and block further updates).

---

P.S.: Long links look really bad with the new theme

Comment: While you have described a good way to get a cryptogrically random number, a lot of programs just call a random() function and leave it at that. Depending on the language the implementation could be extremely predictable. For example Delphi (OO Pascal) has a random that's seeded with the time of day. There is no forced source of random in Windows. I have to say @gbr you really out together a through answer. I'm surprised you don't have more up votes.

Comment: @gbr I have some knowledge in cryptography and I confirm you that several sources of random numbers shall be mixed. Thanks for your deep and complete answer

Comment: @Daisetsu No operating system has a "forced source of random", how would you enforce it? For any software, only its developer knows where there ought to be random data, and he's always free to use https://xkcd.com/221/ if he chooses so...